# Play next and prev song in youtube iframe player

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I have youtube iframe player and I have initialized it with a song and playlist.

```
function OnYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('YTplayer', {
        width: 350,
        height: 200,
        videoId: VideoIdindex,
        playerVars: {
            color: 'white',
            playlist: VideoIdArr
        },
        events: {
            onReady: initialize
        }
    });
}
```

Now I have to trigger the playlist of the player without using the controls that youtube player offers but I have some buttons to play next and prev songs.

I tried to go through the reference website of google developers but was not able to find anything about the controls.

Could someone help me out with this situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve it with this.

```
$('#next').on('click', function () {
    player.nextVideo()
});

$('#prev').on('click', function () {
    player.previousVideo()
});
```